# Spawning HTTPD processes

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, keepalive

Can any confirm how Apache spawns new children ?

As in if I connect to a webserver (HTTP 1.0 / no keep alive) and issue a HTTP /GET I will be spawned a new HTTPD child. If then issue another HTTP /GET then a new TCP connection will be built. 
However will I use the same child process of would I spawn a new one ?

Also if I was using HTTP 1.1 (with keep-alive) and reused the same TCP connection, would the httpd process/spawning be any different to that if I wasnt using keepalive ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I connect to a webserver (HTTP 1.0 / no keep alive) and issue a HTTP /GET I will be spawned a new HTTPD child

No, for the TCP handshake to complete, you've already got a process to handle your request. Since you mention 'processes' this implies you're talking about pre-fork MPM. In which case, the server should already have a pool of available child processes - one of these acquires a mutex to pick up the next incoming connection.

The thread based server works in a similar manner.

The event based server is a completely different kettle of fish and doesn't spawn threads/processes.

> If then issue another HTTP /GET...will I use the same child process

No. And even if you know that you have a keepalive connection, there is no state retained by the server - hence you have to treat it as if it were a new process.

Comment: No - how do you get that from my answer?

Answer (score 1):

There is no universal setting, as this is the most crucial aspect of http server's performance. Generally, Apache tries hard to *avoid* forking (or spawning, as you've called it). Check this out:

http://www.stepwise.hk/blog/check-if-apache-running-prefork-or-worker/

> Multi-Processing Modules (MPMs) are Apache modules that manage the
>   network connections and dispatching the requests. There are two common
>   MPMs available for Apache2, namely, mpm_prefork_module and
>   mpm_worker_module. The mpm_prefork_module uses the traditional model
>   of one process per request, while the mpm_worker_module uses the
>   threaded model which uses multiple processes, each with multiple
>   threads to get better performance with lower overhead.

Manuals for Apache 2.4 says:

> When building Apache, you must choose an MPM to use. There are
>   platform-specific MPMs for some platforms: mpm_netware, mpmt_os2, and
>   [mpm_winnt](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_winnt.html) [for any MS Windows version]. For general Unix-type systems, there are several MPMs from
>   which to choose. The choice of MPM can affect the speed and
>   scalability of the httpd:
>
> - The [worker](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/worker.html) MPM uses multiple child processes with many threads each. Each thread handles one connection at a time. Worker generally
>     is a good choice for high-traffic servers because it has a smaller
>     memory footprint than the prefork MPM.
> - The [event](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/event.html) MPM is threaded like the Worker MPM, but is designed to allow more requests to be served simultaneously by passing off some
>     processing work to supporting threads, freeing up the main threads to
>     work on new requests.
> - The [prefork](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/prefork.html) MPM uses multiple child processes with one thread each. Each process handles one connection at a time.

Comment: Yep I am using prefork.
So if I have this right a new TCP connection is assigned to a new process. However I would of thought it would be better for it to use an exsisting process ?